# Finding substring in list from list of combinations

Tags: python, list, substring, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings like this one

```
cons = ['sum_entries(w) == 1', 'w.T*betas >= 0', 'w >= 0.001']
```

and a substring I want to check for and return the list entry like

```
sub = 'w >'
```

which returns

```
['w >= 0.001']
```

To extend this I want my substring to be a list of possible combinations like

```
sub = ['w <','w =','w >']
```

and still return

```
['w >= 0.001']
```

my current implementation looks like this

```
print([match for match in cons if sub in match])
```

thanks

Comment: decomposition -> minimal question? is it relevant that you search in the list? nope. you already know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

this will solve it

```
print([match for match in cons if any(x in match for x in sub)])
```